# Issues with Dividing by Negative Fractions

Tags: java, class, methods, fractions, divide

I am working on a coding assignment where I am supposed to write the methods to simplify, find gcf, add, subtract, multiply and divide two fractions. I have written all of the methods, but I am having trouble in the divide method because whenever I attempt to divide by a negative fraction (such as the -6/17), it prints 0/1 as the result. Here is my Fraction class with all methods, but the only ones I added are the ones listed above. The rest were provided by my instructor. Here's the class:

```
class Fraction {
    private int numerator = 0; // numerator (and keeps sign)
    private int denominator = 1; // always stores positive value

    public Fraction() {
    }

    public Fraction(int n, int d) {
        if (set(n, d) == false)
           set(0, 1);
    }

    public boolean set(int n, int d) {
        if (d > 0) {
           numerator = n;
           denominator = d;
           return true;
        } else
           return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
       return (numerator + "/" + denominator);
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public double decimal() {
        return (double) numerator / denominator;
    }

    public Fraction simplify(){
       int gcd = GetGcd(this);

       int simpNum = this.numerator;
       int simpDen = this.denominator;

       simpNum /= gcd;
       simpDen /= gcd;

       Fraction f = new Fraction (simpNum, simpDen);
       return f;
    }

    public int GetGcd (Fraction f){
       int testNum = f.numerator;
       int testDen = f.denominator;

       if (testNum < 0)
           testNum = 0 - testNum;
       else if (testDen < 0)
           testDen = 0 - testDen;

       if (testNum == 0){
           return testDen;
       }

       while (testNum != testDen){
           if (testNum > testDen)
              testNum -= testDen;
           else
              testDen -= testNum;

       }
      return testNum;
    }

    public Fraction add (Fraction f){
       int cd = this.denominator * f.denominator;

       int den1 = this.denominator;
       int den2 = f.denominator;
       int num1 = this.numerator * (cd / den1);
       int num2 = f.numerator * (cd / den2);
       int num3 = num1 + num2;
       Fraction f2 = new Fraction (num3, cd);
       f2 = f2.simplify();
       return f2;
    }

    public Fraction subtract (Fraction f){
       int cd = this.denominator * f.denominator;

       int den1 = this.denominator;
       int den2 = f.denominator;
       int num1 = this.numerator * (cd / den1);
       int num2 = f.numerator * (cd / den2);
       int num3 = num1 - num2;

       Fraction f2 = new Fraction (num3, cd);
       f2 = f2.simplify();
       return f2;
    }

    public Fraction multiply (Fraction f){
       int den1 = this.denominator;
       int den2 = f.denominator;
       int num1 = this.numerator;
       int num2 = f.numerator;
       int num3 = num1 * num2;
       int den3 = den1 * den2;

       Fraction f2 = new Fraction (num3, den3);
       f2 = f2.simplify();
       return f2;
    }

    public Fraction divide (Fraction f){
       int den1 = this.denominator;
       int den2 = f.denominator;
       int num1 = this.numerator;
       int num2 = f.numerator;

       int num3 = num1 * den2;
       int den3 = den1 * num2;

       Fraction f2 = new Fraction (num3, den3);
       f2 = f2.simplify();
       return f2;
    }
}
```

And I was given a test code by my instructor that has test fractions. Here it is:

```
    public class FractionTester {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println("\n\nFraction tests:\n");

    Fraction f1 = new Fraction(4, 6);
    Fraction f2 = new Fraction(75, 175);
    Fraction f3 = new Fraction(-6, 17);

    System.out.println(f1 + " simplified = " + f1.simplify());
    System.out.println(f2 + " simplified = " + f2.simplify());
    System.out.println(f3 + " simplified = " + f3.simplify());

    // show that f1, f2, f3 haven't changed
    System.out.println("f1 = " + f1);
    System.out.println("f2 = " + f2);
    System.out.println("f3 = " + f3);

    // arithmetic
    System.out.println(f1 + " + " + f2 + " = " + f1.add(f2));
    System.out.println(f1 + " - " + f2 + " = " + f1.subtract(f2));
    System.out.println(f1 + " * " + f2 + " = " + f1.multiply(f2));
    System.out.println(f1 + " / " + f2 + " = " + f1.divide(f2));
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println(f2 + " + " + f3 + " = " + f2.add(f3));
    System.out.println(f2 + " - " + f3 + " = " + f2.subtract(f3));
    System.out.println(f2 + " * " + f3 + " = " + f2.multiply(f3));
    System.out.println(f2 + " / " + f3 + " = " + f2.divide(f3));
    System.out.println();

    // test 'division by zero' handling
    Fraction zero = new Fraction();
    System.out.println(f2 + " / " + zero + " = " + f2.divide(zero));
  }
}
```

The results should show up like this:

```
4/6 simplified = 2/3
75/175 simplified = 3/7
-6/17 simplified = -6/17
f1 = 4/6
f2 = 75/175
f3 = -6/17
4/6 + 75/175 = 23/21
4/6 - 75/175 = 5/21
4/6 * 75/175 = 2/7
4/6 / 75/175 = 14/9

75/175 + -6/17 = 9/119
75/175 - -6/17 = 93/119
75/175 * -6/17 = -18/119
75/175 / -6/17 = -17/14 (THIS SHOWS UP AS 0/1 INSTEAD...)

75/175 / 0/1 = 0/1
```

I know it's something in the Divide method because when I changed -6/17 to just 6/17 in the last one, it worked and printed 17/14 when simplified. I just have no idea what in the Divide method is not working with negative fractions. Is there maybe something I can add in there to help with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first answer on here might help you bro, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285452/obtaining-wrong-quotient-when-dividing-by-negative-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `divide()`,

```
public Fraction divide (Fraction f){
   int den1 = this.denominator;
   int den2 = f.denominator;
   int num1 = this.numerator;
   int num2 = f.numerator;

   int num3 = num1 * den2;
   int den3 = den1 * num2;

   Fraction f2 = new Fraction (num3, den3);
   ...
```

Assume `this` is positive while `f` is negative. According to your assumption,

```
den1 > 0
den2 > 0
num1 > 0
num2 < 0
num3 = num1 * den2 > 0
den3 = den1 * num2 < 0
```

However, when `new Fraction(num3, den3)` which calls `set()`,

```
public boolean set(int n, int d) {
    if (d > 0) {
       numerator = n;
       denominator = d;
       return true;
    } else
       return false;
}
```

When the denominator is less than 0, you returned `false` which forbids the value from set into the class.

You could inverse signs for both numerator and denominator instead of simply returning `false`.

Comment: When I tried to inverse the signs for the numerator and denominator in `set()`, it output `75/175 / 6/17 = 17/14` for the last division problem. Since this changed the sign of -6/17 to 6/17 for all of them, I tried to inverse the sign of the numerator before multiplying in `Divide()`. This worked except for the sign of the  answer. I got `75/175 / -6/17 = 17/14`. How can I change the sign of the answer to the right answer of -17/14?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out! I put `if(num2 < 0){
   num2 = 0-num2;
   num3 = 0 - num3;
  } ` in between the two multiplication problems in `Divide()` and it printed -17/14. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `set` method to this:

```
public boolean set(int n, int d) {
    if (d > 0) {
       numerator = n;
       denominator = d;
       return true;
    } 
    else if (d < 0) {
        numerator = n * -1;
        denominator = d * -1;
        return true;
    }
    else
       return false;
}
```

Without the second `if` statement, `set` would evaluate to false for fractions with a negative demoninator.  In such cases, the `Fraction` returned by the `divide` method would be 0/1.